# Admob Errors - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob

when i add admob to my app, i got this messages on my console, it doesn't stop and it's a little bit annoying.
Someone can explain me why ? is it serious ?

My **flutter doctor** result :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.6.pre, on Microsoft Windows [version 6.3.9600], locale fr-FR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

*(i tried to downgrade my flutter version, but it did'nt work )*

```
D/eglCodecCommon( 5393): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 5393): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 5 (5) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 5393): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 9 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 5393): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 5393): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 5393): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 5393): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 5393): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 5 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 5393): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 7 (7) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 5393): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
```

Thank you !

Comment: is this creating problem in running an app ??

Comment: not in an emulator, and i didn't test the app on a real device.

Comment: test in real device is the error comming ?